# Hide all <td> with specific content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Looking for suggestions on how to hide all `<td>` in a specific table which match the content of the example below (6 spaces):

```
<td id="" class="">      </td>
```

Firebug shows  as

```
<td class="" id="">

</td>
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? This isn't a "do my job for me" site - you show what you've tried, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: I've tried loads of goes with :contains but cant seem to get it to work ;)

Comment: Post the code, contains should work unless those white spaces are actually something else.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to target the actual `<td>` elements based on their `id` and `class` attributes, you could use the [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to handle that :

```
// Hide any <td> elements that have an empty ID and class attributes
$('td[id=""][class=""]').hide();
```

Likewise, if you wanted to target these elements based on their contents, then you could use the [`contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector :

```
// Hide any elements that contain six consecutive spaces
$('td:contains("      ")').hide();
```

However, if you wanted to target elements that contained **exactly** that content, you would likely need to handle it through a [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) call :

```
// Hide any <td> elements that have content that is exactly six spaces
$('td').filter(function(){ $(this).text() == '      '; }).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Something like:

```
  $( "td:contains('      ')" ).css( "display", "none" );
```

Comment: Ok, so with a loop through approach - how would this work?

Comment: What does a loop have to do with anything?  Why use the verbose `css()` when `hide()` does the same thing and simplier?

Comment: @ErikPhilips just habit I guess, beside the .hide() will save the previous state of the elements.... which wasn't part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason `:contains` isn't working, you can use jquery's `.html()` method in a loop to check the contents:

```
$('td').each(function() {
  if ($(this).html() === '      ') {
    $(this).hide()
  }
})
```